# Does there exist an irrational number $x$ such that both $x^π$ and $π^x$ are also irrational?

Tags: irrational-numbers, pi

Can we find a number, let's say $x$ that's not a simple fraction, and if you raise it to the power of $π$ or raise $π$ to the power of $x$, both results end up being not simple fractions too?

Comment: There certainly exists such a number. The set of rationals is countable, and since both $x \mapsto x^\pi$ and $x \mapsto \pi^x$ are injective, there are only countably many $x$ such that $x^\pi$ is rational, and countably many where $\pi^x$ is rational. Unioning these countable sets, you get the countable set of $x$ where one or the other is rational. The complement in $(0, \infty)$ is uncountable, and in particular, non-empty. Of course, this does not help you find such an $x$!

Comment: If for any irrationnal, atleast one of $x^\pi$ or $\pi^x$ is rationnal, then the irrationnal are countable. You can try showing this, and if you don't already know it, that there is uncountably many irrationnals

Comment: @TheoBendit damn, I was too slow.. :(

Comment: @Shika Any of these will work fine as full answers.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger There is a reason why I posted a comment (aside from my general anxiety about the post-EoQS MSE dark ages). The title asks "Does there exist...", while the body asks "Can we find...". The latter is more difficult. For example, the $x = 2$ case is not known (obviously $\pi^2$ is as transcendental as $\pi$, but $2^\pi$ [could be rational](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Is_2_to_the_power_of_Pi_Rational%3F) for all we know).

Comment: There are a number of close votes so far (none of them is mine), and no one has commented as to what makes the Question off-topic.  It is a Problem Statement Question (PSQ) lacking any context.  It would be simple enough for the OP to add context, such as where the problem arose, what related results are known to them, or even what makes the problem important or difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Following Akiva's advice, I'm posting this as a full answer, but I'll leave the details to you:

If for any irrational, atleast one of $x^\pi$ or $π^x$ is rational, then the set of irrationals injects in a union of two countable sets: Which ones ?
Why is this absurd ?